# My Publishing Console is no longer available

Tags: console

When I am logged into the AppExchange, I do not have the option access my publishing console to make updates to our listing. How can I get back to this to make updates?[image]

Answer (score 0):

All publishing is now done through the Partner Community. Use your credentials to log-in to the Partner Community and you'll find the new Publishing Console. While you're there, I highly recommend you take a look at the many other updated materials since the ISV program has significantly changed in the last few months.